# How to check if array is empty using if condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

respons is coming back empty [] for `this.rxInfos` but below if condtion never executed any idea what is missing here ?

main.js

```
if (!Array.isArray(this.rxInfos) && this.rxInfos.length === 0) {
            return this.errorHandler(request, 'no rx found in the cache');
        }
```

Comment: Using `&&`, you are checking that both are true at the same time.

Comment: An empty array is still an array

Comment: @bugs The OP is checking if it is NOT an array

Comment: Use `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: read it out loud: `if (not an Array AND the length is zero)`

Comment: @Marie which is the wrong thing to do

Comment: "An empty array is still an array" they arent checking for an empty array. they are checking for a zero-length string. So Alfabravo is correct. They need `||`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check not an array or if no length.

The first part

```
!Array.isArray(this.rxInfos)
```

is `true`, if the value of `this.rxInfos` is not an array.

The [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) allows to end the check, which is important, if the first operand it [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). If not, then an array is given and the second part

```
!this.rxInfos.length
```

with the length and their [logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) is evaluated and that means, if a length of zero, the last part is true or if the length has another value than zero, the part yields `false`.

```
if (!Array.isArray(this.rxInfos) || !this.rxInfos.length) {
    return this.errorHandler(request, 'no rx found in the cache');
}
```

Comment: The solution was to use `||` not `&&`, you made the change but didnt really explain why you made the change. Your length check and theirs accomplish the same thing so it is really inconsequential.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove first !

```
 if (this.rxInfos !== undefined && Array.isArray(this.rxInfos) && this.rxInfos.length === 0) { return this.errorHandler(request, 'no rx found in the cache'); }
```